# Angular front-end getting error when calling api on c# back-end

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular front-end and a C# webAPI back-end.  The Angular front-end can retrieve data from other URLs (e.g. http://reqres.in/api/users and json-server --watch db.json).  The C# webAPI successfully returns data to API calls (entered in browser and sent from Postman (Get, http://localhost:49566/api/people)).
When the front-end calls the back-end, gets the following:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
> (XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:49566/people

Any suggestions on what the problem is, or whether it is on the front-end or the back-end?

I have reviewed several Angular httpclient examples; but continue to experience the same thing--works with other URLs; but not with my C# webAPI's URL.

I have tried adding a post option; but that did not resolve it.

C# code:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        return SQLiteDataAccess.GetPeople();
    }
```

Angular data service code:

```
export class DataService {
  people: object;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    searchClick(searchString: string) {
    return console.log('clicked ' + searchString);
  }

  getPeople() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200/',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:49566/api/People', httpOptions )  
}
}
```

What I need is for the front-end to successfully retrieve data from the back-end; so I can display it.

Comment: There is something odd as you say the url is `http://localhost:49566/api/people` and the error contains `http://localhost:49566/people`. Have a look in there.

Comment: Sorry, error on my part.  The correct error should read http://localhost:49566/api/people.  I have tried both adjusting the c# to both api/people and /people; both error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:49566/api/People', httpOptions )
```

to

```
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:49566/api/people', httpOptions )
```

the URL is case-sensitive.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.  Now the error I get is "Http failure response for http://localhost:49566/api/people: 0 Unknown Error" with a status of 0.

Comment: I have gotten Wireshark to work now, and can see that the front-end is sending an OPTIONS call instead of a GET.  Any ideas why, or how to change the Angular front-end to send a GET?  NOTE:  when I add OPTIONS on the back-end, this is the error that I get "[CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:4200' did not find 'http://localhost:4200' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://localhost:49566/api/people'."  Not sure how to correct that either.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  How do I remove the CORS headers?  Is that by removing the ", httpOptions" from the this.http.get?  If so, I tried that and still get the same error.

Comment: If removing the CORS from the `httpOptions` is not working, please enable CORS in your C# code to accept requests from `localhost:4200`. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to CORS (on server-side) and method signature on server side.

First of all, enable CORS in your API code (C#). Please search MSDN for appropriate namespaces/dlls (e.g. `System.Web.Cors`) needed.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();
```

In API controller-derived class (e.g.), please do this to ensure the CORS is allowed. `*` means all URLs are allowed. Change as per your client (Angular app uri) needs.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Provides API for Order entity.
    /// </summary>
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class OrderController : ApiController
    {
```

In CORS, a pre-flight request with the `OPTIONS` method is sent, so that the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters. It is sent before sending a `GET` or `POST`.

Coming back to API code, in `web.config`, please ensure you have the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

`<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` ensures that IIS doesn't intercept `OPTIONS` requests.

Also in `web.config`, do the following. This ensures `GET`, `POST` and `OPTIONS` methods are allowed.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>            
        <!--...omitted for brevity-->

        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
```

Finally:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            return SQLiteDataAccess.GetPeople();
        }
```

There's no need to do anything about CORS in client-side code in Angular. Hope that helps.